# Byte size of an NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, cocoa, memory, nsdictionary

This may sound like a completely stupid question, but how can I get the size in bytes of an NSDictionary? Can I convert it to NSData, and then get the length of that?

Help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should say more about why you care about the size of the dictionary in bytes, because the answer might be different depending.

In general, the "size" of an NSDictionary's footprint in memory is not something you can see or care about. It abstracts its storage mechanism from the programmer, and uses some form of overhead beyond the actual data it's storing.

You can, however, serialize the dictionary to NSData. If the contents of the dictionary are only "primitive" types like NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, NSData, NSDictionary, you can use the NSPropertyListSerialization class to turn it into a binary property list, which will be about the most compact byte representation of its contents that you can get:

```
NSDictionary * myDictionary = /* ... */;
NSData * data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:myDictionary
    format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:NULL];    
NSLog(@"size: %d", [data length]);
```

If it contains other custom objects, you could use NSKeyedArchiver to archive it to an NSData, but this will be significantly larger and requires the cooperation of your custom classes.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great! The reason I am using it is to get the size of http headers sent back by [NSHTTPURLResponse allHeaderFields], and see the size of those headers (trying to monitor network usage)... unless there is a better way?

Comment: The more direct way to look at network traffic is to look at network traffic. :) Run a web proxy and inspect the traffic? Look into Charles Proxy on the desktop, or Wireshark or something like that.

Comment: 'dataFromPropertyList:format:errorDescription:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error: instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the size of any class by calling this:

```
#import "objc/runtime.h"
int size = class_getInstanceSize([NSDictionary class]);
```

This will return you the size of the class, but not the actual size occupied by an instantiated object. If you want the size of an instantiated object:

```
#import "malloc/malloc.h"
int size = malloc_size(myObject);
```

Comment: That only gives you the size of instance variables of the instance, it does not give you the size of anything the object allocates nor is there any way to do so.  It also won't work for `NSDictionary`, since there is never an instance of `NSDictionary` in your app;  just instances of private subclasses.