# malloc_size can't determine clipboard content size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, clipboard

I'm trying to detect the size of an object in the clipboard. I tried:

```
UIPasteBoard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
for(NSDictionary *myDictionary in [pb items]){
    NSLog(@"%zu", malloc_size((__bridge const void *)(myDictionary)));
}
```

The problem is that this returns a similar number whether there's one word (plain text) in the clipboard or a movie!

How can I find a a reliable size for the objects in the clipboard?

Comment: This may be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5207253/1407017

Comment: @Amar actually that is helpful and works for text and movie, however it returns 0 for an image in the clipboard

Comment: `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` can give you image data from which you can get the byte size.

Comment: Note that doing so may cause an allocation of that size, so if the point of checking was to avoid spiking memory usage, that won't be an approach you want to take. (Although if it's on the pasteboard, IIUC it's already in memory, so...)

Comment: @ipmcc yes that is the point, what's a better way? However I'm finding the size of an object in the clipboard, so are you saying that it may not be an issue?

Comment: @Hope4You: Edited my answer to show some code that should hopefully measure the size of objects on the pasteboard yet avoid making copies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, `malloc_size` only includes the "structure" of the NSDictionary, *not* any memory it allocates and keeps pointers to.  In short, `malloc_size` is pretty useless for this purpose.

To get a sense of the size of the object(s) on the pasteboard you could try this:

```
UIPasteboard* pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSUInteger totalSize = 0;
for (NSString* type in pb.pasteboardTypes)
{
    NSData* data = [pb dataForPasteboardType: type];
    totalSize += data.length;
}
```

Comment: Can you help me understand how this will use less memory than the method at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5207253/1407017? It seems that both methods require a new allocation?

Comment: `dataForPasteboardType:` will return you an `NSData` object that, in the common case, already exists in memory. Inquiring as to its length should not cause any further memory to be allocated. Serializing a dictionary with NSPropertyListSerialization will force an NSData to be created to hold the serialized version of the dictionary.